# Error: List has no rows for assignment to SObject

Tags: apex, visualforce, list-button

i have created one button on record top beside the clone button, when clicked, execute code that would make a new version record with the same name and append today's date on the end of the name to distinguish it from the original.i created apex class and custom list button but the i clicked on button so java script does'not working on this.so below error occour during click on the button.

How should i do this ?

**List has no rows for assignment to SObject**

**Apex Class**

Public Class CloneVersionwithTextController{

```
Public List<Master_Service_Agreement_Version__c> msalist{get;set;}
public string msaid{get;set;}

Public CloneVersionwithTextController(){

    msaid = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('id');

    List<Master_Service_Agreement_Version__c> msalist = new List<Master_Service_Agreement_Version__c>();
    Master_Service_Agreement_Version__c msa = [SELECT ID, Name, Status__c FROM Master_Service_Agreement_Version__c WHERE Id = : msaid];
    Master_Service_Agreement_Version__c msaCopy = msa.clone(false,true);
    insert msaCopy;
    system.debug('===msaCopy===='+msaCopy);
    List<MSA_Text_Block__c> mtext = new List<MSA_Text_Block__c>();
    system.debug('===mtext===='+mtext);
    mtext = [SELECT Id, Name, Service__c, Order_within_Service__c,Master_Service_Agreement_Version__r.ID,LastModifiedBy.Name FROM MSA_Text_Block__c WHERE Master_Service_Agreement_Version__r.ID = : msa.Id];
    for(MSA_Text_Block__c c : mtext)
    {
        MSA_Text_Block__c mtextCopy = c.clone(false,true);
        mtextCopy.Master_Service_Agreement_Version__c = msaCopy.Id;
        mtext.add(mtextCopy);
    }
    system.debug('===msaList===='+msaList);
    if(msaList.size() > 0){
        msaList.get(0).Name = msaList.get(0).Name + Datetime.now();
    }
    update msaList;
}
}
```

**Visualforce Page**

```
 <apex:page controller="CloneVersionwithTextController" >
   <apex:detail subject="{!msaid}" relatedList="true" title="false"/>
 </apex:page>
```

**List button code**

```
{!URLFOR("/apex/CloneVersionwithText", "")}?msaid={!Master_Service_Agreement_Version__c.Id}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Master_Service_Agreement_Version__c msa = [SELECT ID, Name, Status__c FROM Master_Service_Agreement_Version__c WHERE Id = : msaid];
```

in this line if you don't get any record then you will get this error. convert msa into `List<Master_Service_Agreement_Version__c> msaList` and first check size if it is `msaList.size()>0` the refer first element. It will solve your problem.Thanks.

Comment: Master_Service_Agreement_Version__c msaCopy = msalist.clone(false,true);
this line error show that:
 Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [List<Master_Service_Agreement_Version__c>].clone(Boolean, Boolean)

Comment: i used msalist but did'not solve the issue

Comment: Master_Service_Agreement_Version__c msaCopy = msalist[0].clone(false,true); try this

Comment: tushar i need your help show new error:-List index out of bounds: 0

Comment: Please let me know.

Comment: i have some changes in code but does'not working

Comment: What error you are getting.

Comment: List index out of bounds: 0

Comment: first check the size of list. Please check in condition If(list.size() >0)

Comment: and if you are getting any other error then post as new question and make this as answer.

Comment: i send your code

Comment: talk after some times

Answer (score 0):

{!URLFOR("/apex/CloneVersionwithText", "")}?**msaid**={!Master_Service_Agreement_Version__c.Id}

In your button you use **msaid** variable but in class you are getting **id** variable. I think if you change this line

```
msaid = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('id');
```

with this

```
msaid = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('msaid');
```

it will work just fine. You can test you are getting a correct id with putting a system debug line after msaid line.

```
system.debug('msaid = ' + msaid);
```

UPDATE: DML not allowed

```
Public List<Master_Service_Agreement_Version__c> msalist{get;set;}
public string msaid{get;set;}

Public CloneVersionwithTextController(){}
public void myFunction(){
    msaid = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('msaid');

        List<Master_Service_Agreement_Version__c> msalist = new List<Master_Service_Agreement_Version__c>();
        Master_Service_Agreement_Version__c msa = [SELECT ID, Name, Status__c FROM Master_Service_Agreement_Version__c WHERE Id = : msaid];
        Master_Service_Agreement_Version__c msaCopy = msa.clone(false,true);
        insert msaCopy;
        system.debug('===msaCopy===='+msaCopy);
        List<MSA_Text_Block__c> mtext = new List<MSA_Text_Block__c>();
        system.debug('===mtext===='+mtext);
        mtext = [SELECT Id, Name, Service__c, Order_within_Service__c,Master_Service_Agreement_Version__r.ID,LastModifiedBy.Name FROM MSA_Text_Block__c WHERE Master_Service_Agreement_Version__r.ID = : msa.Id];
        for(MSA_Text_Block__c c : mtext)
        {
            MSA_Text_Block__c mtextCopy = c.clone(false,true);
            mtextCopy.Master_Service_Agreement_Version__c = msaCopy.Id;
            mtext.add(mtextCopy);
        }
        system.debug('===msaList===='+msaList);
        if(msaList.size() > 0){
            msaList.get(0).Name = msaList.get(0).Name + Datetime.now();
        }
        update msaList;
    }
    }
```

Visualforce Page

```
<apex:page controller="CloneVersionwithTextController" action="{!myFunction}">
   <apex:detail subject="{!msaid}" relatedList="true" title="false"/>
 </apex:page>
```

Comment: show error "DML currently not allowed"

Comment: DML operations are not allowed in constructor method. You need to move insert and update out of the constructor. If this code will work only once when you clicked the button you can write a new method and add this method in visualforce page action tag. I've updated my answer to make this change.